# What would a criminal defense attorney charge in late 19th century America?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, law, old-west

What would a criminal defense attorney charge on the [American frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_frontier#The_Postbellum_West) in a murder trial in 1885? I am specifcally interested in what it would have cost three cowpokes to mount a murder defence in Rapid City, Dakota Territory 1885. I know they were defended by Colonel William Parker who was a successful lawyer and politician in the Territory at the time, but so far I have found no clue what his fees were.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Would also significantly help if you documented your [preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786).  I imagine that the answer is highly variable - urban setting vs rural, proximity of a  a railroad, the presence of skilled attorney vs having to recruit one from elsewhere,   Of course, the cost will range from zero (self representation) to what the market will bear.